# Pull data from firestore using useEffect works on re-render only

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getDocs, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';


const Home = () => {

    const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
    const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "data");

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPosts = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
            let postListArray = []
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                const post = { ...doc.data() }
                postListArray.push(post)
            });
            setPostList(postListArray)
        };
        getPosts();
        console.log(postList);
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>test</div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

On loading, the console.log returned an empty array. The spooky thing is when i changed anything , for example

```
    return (
        <div>test_epic</div>
    );
```

The console.log shows that it is an array. Anyone has any idea as to why? Please refer to the screepcap as attached.

[the first render on loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTycb.png)

[I changed anything and components rerendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9b2a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting state in react is asynchronous, so the data is loaded and the state is set but the `console.log` statement is executed before the setting state async operation is complete

To make it a bit more clear this is how it works step by step

1. Component is rendered and `postList` is initialized with a value of `[]`
2. `useEffect` is triggered
3. Data is fetched
4. A *call* to set a new value of `postList` is placed using `setPostList` (key here is a call is placed not that the data is actually updated)
5. You print `console.log` with a value from Step 1
6. The call from Step 4 is complete and *now* the data is actually updated

Here is an [article](https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia) that explains it with examples

And here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/3088146) that explains this deeply

Comment: the article recommended using useEffect. Is it useEffect is synchronous but useState is asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, you should use `useEffect` and this behavior in your question is how it is supposed to work. This shouldn't affect your React app